# GCM android can't send message on some device?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I created an android app using GCM, and successfully sent message to another device.

But with the same app from another device nothing happens. Why My GCM cant sent any message from another device!?

Code:

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
```

Guide me if something wrong with this code.

Comment: php code with java tag? you have some trouble.

Comment: What does the echo of $result show you? That should hold the answer as to what's wrong.

Comment: this echo of $result
{"multicast_id":7581595512129243700,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1393508903773800%f11e78b0f9fd7ecd"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Check for GCM service apk availability on device.

```
/**
 * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
 * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
 * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
 */
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ttl to 0 and do the curl call. If you don't specify ttl, the gcm can send it within 4 weeks of time. Your response shows it's success but that doesn't mean it's delivered.

```
{ "collapse_key": "score_update",
  "time_to_live": 108,
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "data": {
    "score": "4x8",
    "time": "15:16.2342"
  },
  "registration_ids":["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

The payload with all the fields. Refer this [gcm http server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html)

Comment: yes.gcm response is succes..where i can setting ttl to 0 and do the curl call in that code ? or maybe you have link or some tutorial look like my case above?

Comment: are there any terms of android version can use gcm?

Comment: gcm supports minimum android api level 8

Comment: it doesnt matter with my api,I use api level 8+..
I've try in 2 device,first device samsung galaxy gio,and second device galaxy ace..
first day I tried send successfully  message from ace to gio and receive the message,but from gio to ace i get nothing.
second day I get strange problem with my gcm, I send successfully  message from gio to Ace and receive the message,but from Ace to gio i get nothing.. the problem second day is opposite of first day
why I get problem like this?how i can solve the problem?